# How to get the 50 last lines processed by the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, trace, traceback

**How is it possible to get a full trace of the 50 last lines processed by the Python interpreter?**

Example:

**myprogram1.py**

---

```
import mymodule1

mymodule1.dosomething()
```

**mymodule1.py**

---

```
def dosomething():
    a = 12
    a += 30
    print a
```

**Expected output of the "trace" (that would display all that has been done, recursively in imported modules) of myprogram1.py**

---

```
import mymodule1
mymodule1.dosomething()
a = 12
a += 30
print a
```

Comment: Google `python trace`, my friend. Devote 15 minutes to research

Comment: Probably, using `sys.settrace`. But I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. There's probably a better solution.

Comment: @delnan : Sometimes I import a big module for just 2 or 3 simple functions... If I could *trace* all that has been done when calling these functions, I could simply copy/paste it into my code, without relying anymore on the external module. That is the reason.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I tried `trace`, but it did not recurse in imported modules

Comment: @Basj No offense meant, but that's silly. Often that's not worth the hassle. In simple cases, it's simpler to just do by hand. And in all other cases, it's much harder than simply copy/paste-ing the last X lines executed, since module relationships, names, etc. will all be messed up.